# Create list with random input for SQL multiple line input

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I want to learn Python and SQLite by programming a game (text based). I would like to insert data into a SQLite DB. I created a tabel for players

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE player(ID_Player INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Age INT, Name VARCHAR, Position VARCHAR, Skill INT, Value INT)''')
```

Now I would like to insert n entries for this table. And for each column, I would like to apply a function that determines what should be entered.

- for age: randint(18,33))
- for Name: names.get_full_name(gender='male')
- for Position: random.choice(positions)
- for Skill: randint(50,100)
- for Value: randint(500000,5000000)

If I manually create the lists, which looks like this

```
multi_lines =[ (25,'Playern Name1','TW',95,45000000),
               (26,'Playern Name2','ST',75,3500000),
               (32,'Playern Name3','IV',85,25000000),]
```

than I can execute them and they are inserted to my DB with the function `c.executemany('INSERT INTO player(age, name, position, skill, value)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', multi_lines)` 
I tried to determine the inputs om `c.executemany` but this did not work.

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO player(Age, Name, Position, Skill, Value)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',\
               (randint(18,33),names.get_full_name(gender='male'),random.choice(positions),randint(50,100), randint(500000,50000000) ))
```

Next, I tried to make many lists and put them into an empty list:

```
lst = []
positions = ['TW', 'IV', 'MF', 'ST']

for i in range(2):
    lst.append(randint(18,33))
    lst.append(names.get_full_name(gender='male'))
    lst.append(random.choice(positions))
    lst.append(randint(50,100))
    lst.append(randint(500000,5000000))

print  lst
```

the output of this was `[19, u'Ricardo Moore', 'ST', 68, 3298618, 26, u'Carl Cole', 'ST', 92, 3380302]`, however, I would like to create  outputs like in `multi_lines`. What could be a logical way to do this? Or more specifically, how can I create a list which is in another list ?

```
main_list = [
    (list_1),
    (list_2),
    (list_n)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *list of lists* for `executemany()`:

```
positions = ['TW', 'IV', 'MF', 'ST']
multi_lines = [[
        randint(18,33),
        names.get_full_name(gender='male'),
        random.choice(positions),
        randint(50,100),
        randint(500000,5000000)
    ]
    for i in range(2)
]

c.executemany('INSERT INTO player(Age, Name, Position, Skill, Value)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', multi_lines)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I was almost there just could not figure out where to put the for statement.